# Serial flagging: Is there such a thing? Should there be?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

While going through my (almost) daily dose of Low Quality queue reviews, I noticed something that seemed kind of odd, and was wondering if it might be worth a discussion/investigation.

There were a whole bunch of clear link-only answers. Which by itself is not unusual, they sometimes seem to arrive in batches. But what jumped out this time was that most of these link-only answers were several years old, and came from **the same user**.

I don't have the tools to know if these flags came from an automatic script, or if the posts were flagged by a user. But in either case, it seems somewhat worrying:

1. If it's a script, why would it pick out posts that are almost exclusively from a single user? There must be a huge number of link-only answers if you run searches that go a few years back. Unless this user was exceptionally "productive" at posting link-only answers, this looks non-random at first sight.
2. If a user flagged the posts, it looks targeted. In that case, it would seem very similar to serial upvotes/downvotes to me. The flags were absolutely justified. But for serial upvotes/downvotes, the communicated policy is that they are always wrong, even if the votes are justified based on the quality of the posts. Just the fact of focusing attention to a specific user is considered unacceptable when it comes to votes. Shouldn't the same apply to flags?

I'd rather not post the username if it can be avoided. Since the user might already have been singled out, I'd rather not make it worse by engaging the meta effect. But I can provide it (and links to reviews) if it's found necessary and worthwhile.

Comment: serial voting is different (and dangerous) in that it is not only anonymous but also doesn't pass any review. With flags things are different, these have effect only if reviewers / moderators agree with them

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yeah we get serial spam/NAA flags sometimes. We've had someone use up all 50 of their daily flags, over the course of *several days*, all on posts by the same user. That's several *multiples of 50* in flags.

I mean, if you're highlighting actual problems, then more power to you. But to expend all of your flags over a single user seems extremely inefficient (and not to mention a pretty cheap way of farming flags for badges). If you find that a particular user's posts have consistent problems, here's how to save yourself (and everyone else) some time: raise a single custom flag explaining to us what the exact problem is with the user's posts, then move on elsewhere.

Not all of these flagging sprees turn out to come from a personal vendetta — for instance, there were no signs of any scuffle between the two users I mentioned above, just some *deeply* concentrated flagging — but to those that do, I must commend the perps for having the guts to call the cops on someone just because you didn't like them.

As people whose primary role is to handle flags, we moderators actively monitor users' flagging patterns and will usually be able to spot any targeted patterns of flagging and address users accordingly. If you ever see anything suspicious, please don't hesitate to flag it for our attention; we'll be more than happy to look into it. Leave it to us to determine on a case-by-case basis the nature of the flags.

Comment: Will this apply if you flag lots of questions from random users?

Comment: @PythonMaster: In that case, you're not really targeting anybody, so no. That said, there are different kinds of patterns, such as patterns of really inaccurate flags, which will get you warned or flag-banned just as well. As long as you're even a little bit careful with your flags, you should be fine.