# When should I flag an answer?

Tags: support, answers, flags

I'm really trying hard not to target or call anyone out so I will refrain from posting any names unless it is deemed helpful. That said, I came across an answer today that had been directly copied and pasted from another site. I flagged it and it was deleted.

Great...

So now I'm curious about this user so I go onto their profile and see two other answers they've posted two hours and 19 hours ago - both with zero votes.

That may not seem like a big deal, but after looking at one answer they'd posted code with no explanation - so I downvoted and moved on.

I come to the next answer they posted - giving code which doesn't make a lot of sense because the question was missing details that made reading the question and the answer confusing. If that wasn't enough though they were giving out incorrect information. So I downvoted and moved on.

I have also left comments on the answers so they can improve them.

So with this scenario I kept thinking "Should this be flagged?" So I did a Google search for when to raise a flag.

The first post on Google is slightly helpful: [How to raise helpful flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173755/how-to-raise-helpful-flags)

But everything that follows is not really helpful at all.

The key questions that I feel I need to know are:

1. Should flags be used sparingly?
2. Is there a process you should complete before flagging (e.g. comment/downvote)?
3. Is an answer with correct code but telling users incorrect information worthy of a downvote or a flag?

---

These are the main points off the top of my head. If we could make a detailed guide on flagging and everything to go with it, I believe it could be super beneficial, especially since a lot of flags are raised every day.

If people had some due diligence when raising a flag it could go a long way.

Comment: "So now i'm curious about this guy so I go onto his profile and see 2 other answers hes posted 2 hours and 19 hours ago both with zero votes.That may not seem like a big deal but after looking at one answer he post code no explanation so I downvote and move on." Just FYI, this is considered user targeting and it's usually quite frowned upon (though some mods approve of it when it is used to bring problem users or content to their attention).

Comment: Wasnt trying to target I just saw it as the start of a bad series of answers @TylerH

Comment: This has been done for the particular Not An Answer flag: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/7795130).

Comment: @CoderJoe Going though questions/answers/comments from user's profile is what "user targeting" is on SO. There is almost no chance that one would over course of couple minutes naturally see two answer by the same person that were posted 20 hours apart. If you feel that there is serious problem with user's account - raising moderator flag would be appropriate (i.e. all posts are plagiarized content), but "user posts low quality answers" is not a reason to flag. You may want to research "serial voting" topic on meta too.

Comment: Relevant: [Serial flagging: Is there such a thing? Should there be?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268356/1364007)

Comment: @TylerH: Yes; it is considered targeting and I accidentally did it [once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365038/5779732). I avoided to do it then after; but I (and many others) still think this is necessary if the crap is being removed. I understand that this may be miss-used. But, how to stop the miss-use is different issue; any feature can be miss-used anyway.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/332043

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Should flags be used sparingly?

No, not really. If you come across anything that you feel needs to be looked at by a moderator, then you should flag it.

Don't worry that you’re creating too much work for us. This is our job; we've volunteered to do it for the good of the community. If the community is raising more flags than the moderator team is able to handle, then that's a sign we need to expand the size of the moderator team.

*However*, you should only use flags when there's an actual reason to flag.

In other words: **flags don't need to be used *sparingly*, but they need to be used *correctly*.**

> Is there a process you should complete before flagging (e.g. comment/downvote)?

No, not really.

Feel free to downvote, of course, whenever you feel so compelled. But it's almost never necessary (and often ill-advised) to leave a comment on a post that you're flagging.

> Is an answer with correct code but telling users incorrect information worthy of a downvote or a flag?

A downvote. Do not flag answers because of technical issues. Moderators do not judge technical correctness.

---

There are two types of standard flags that can be raised on answers: "not an answer" and "very low quality". You can find guidance for how these flags are interpreted and in what circumstances they should be used in the following Meta Q&A:

- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)
- [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)
- [When is a *closeable* question a *very low quality* question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-a-very-low-quality-question)

It's simpler than everyone makes it:

- **If something is posted as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question, then flag as "not an answer".** That includes answers that are completely irrelevant to the question (e.g., because they're not written in English, or because they refer to an entirely different programming language than the question is about), answers that are attempts to ask a new/follow-up question, answers that are merely saying "me too" or "thanks", and answers that contain no content within the body of the answer itself (often misleadingly referred to as "link-only" answers). Incoherent garbage is also a candidate for flagging as "not an answer".
- **The "very low quality" flag is** for posts that are useless garbage and need to be deleted. Interpret this flag as **"a moderator needs to delete this"**, and you will never go wrong.
- ***Don't* flag answers because you don't think they're good enough** (e.g., they contain only code and have no explanation), **and *don't* flag answers because you don't think they're the *right* answer** (i.e., flags should not be used to indicate technical correctness). These are both downvote reasons. Moderators can't do anything about such answers.

Flags don't mean "please edit". If a post needs to be edited for any reason, then you can (and should) make that edit yourself. That could be because an otherwise useful answer contains abusive language, or because a link has gone dead and needs to be removed/replaced, or because the answer contains code that is incorrectly formatted and thus unreadable. Moderator intervention is not required in any of those cases.

Does that help? Again, don't overthink it. Flag stuff you see that you think a moderator needs to deal with. Note that, for *answers*, "deal with" pretty much means "delete". If you don't think it should be deleted, you probably shouldn't be flagging as either "not an answer" or "very low quality".

(Of course, there are plenty of reasons you'd use a *custom* moderator flag when you didn't want something to be deleted. For example, you suspect sockpuppetry, or you need some information redacted, or... whatever.)

Custom flags should also be raised on answers that are plagiarized; you need a custom flag so you can provide moderators with a link to the original source from which you suspect the answer is plagiarized. "Not an answer" and "very low quality" do not make the problem sufficiently obvious. Try to avoid making moderators guess at what you mean or are having a problem with.

Comment: I agree with most of this, except "it's almost never necessary (and often ill-advised) to leave a comment on a post that you're flagging." Shouldn't we be telling the author on why we're flagging so they can avoid making the same mistake in the future?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be telling the author anything, for a whole bunch of different reasons. First, it's a waste of time to leave comments on things that are about to get deleted. Second, it's unnecessary, because the system already has automatic help that informs people why answers are deleted. Third, it's a bad idea because it leads to hurt feelings, noisy discussion, and revenge targeting of the commenter. Plus more counter-indications I haven't time or space to include here. A flag is an escalation mechanism. If you are calling in a moderator, the time for a comment has come and gone. @pik

Comment: I guess I didn't mention it in my previous comment, but the primary reason I comment on posts I flag is to educate the people reviewing the flag on why I flagged it. I could use a custom mod flag, but it's not always the moderators who review flags (NAA flags, close flags, etc). That would leave only your third point: "it leads to hurt feelings, noisy discussion, and revenge targeting of the commenter". At least in my experience this doesn't happen if the comment explains how to *solve* the problem and the commenter does not perceive it as hostile (and, in my experience, they usually don't).

Comment: If it's unclear why you're flagging something as "not an answer" or "very low quality", you should be raising a custom moderator flag. You should only use NAA and VLQ when the problems are *obvious*, and in that case, there's no point in leaving a comment to point out the obvious.

Comment: Here's one example I frequently come across: an answer is an exact duplicate of another answer to the same question. This is something the community can handle through reviewing in low quality posts. Is it immediately obvious that it's a duplicate of another answer? No, it's easy to miss it. But does it require a mod to delete? No, the community can handle it. That is, if they know what the problem with the answer is. I don't think a custom flag is necessary in these cases.

Comment: @CodyGray Yea this was very informative thank you

Answer (score 8):

You thinking an answer is not a useful answer does not merit a flag, no.  If you think an answer isn't useful you can downvote it, if you have suggestions for how it can be improved, you can comment.  Those are the tools available for answers that are not useful answers to the question.